# Python Tkinter calendar widget import error in .py file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import, importerror, tkcalendar

I am using tkcalendar widget to make a calendar in Python.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkcalendar

def print_sel():
    date = cal.selection_get()
    root.destroy()

def quit1():
    root.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
cal = tkcalendar.Calendar(root, font="Arial 11", selectmode='day',
                            year=2016, month=1, day=1)
cal.pack()
ttk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=print_sel).pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
ttk.Button(root, text="Back", command=quit1).pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
date = ''
root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that the code above works fine when run in Jupyter notebook but when converted and run as .py file.I get this error:

```
import tkcalendar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkcalendar'
```

When I pip install tkcalendar I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: tkcalendar in...

Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=0a in...

Requirement already satisfied: babel in...
```

Comment: is your Jupyter and .py Python interpreter the same (loading the packages from the same path)? If it is, then it shouldn't create a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first suggestion: You should check the location for PYTHON installation path and from that directory go to cmd -> and type: pip installs tkcalendar. If the installation is successful then the problem is in your interpreter selection where your scripts are running.

Anyway, as per your problem description, It looks **your interpreter selection where your scripts are running** so try first this.

Thanks..Enjoy Coding.

Comment: I am running the .py file with cmd so e.g the file with my code is named Calendar.py.I use cmd and run Calendar.py. So I am not sure how to check the location for python installation path you mentioned.

Comment: import sys
print(sys.path)

Comment: Try using the above code in cmd. You will get the path for Python installation